# Adding windows credentials on google cloud platform - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-cloud-platform, credentials

I have had a difficulty to add credentials and deploy any asp.net application. I have created account and application in the google cloud platform but when i have tried to add windows credentials in visual studio(2017) it has shown this error. It has shown it after the program asking me to reset the password for the specific username. What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your system isn't finding the "gcloud" command, which is part of the Google Cloud SDK.

1. [Install the Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#windows).
2. Ensure that the gcloud command is added to your system's `PATH` environment variable. If you use the interactive installer this last step should be done for you.
3. Restart your system or IDE if it isn't picking up the change after installing the SDK. If it still isn't finding the application, you might need to manually edit your environment variable or point your IDE to the specific SDK location.

Comment: There is a problem with the SDK installation. Every time it shows this error - https://pasteboard.co/GIXBLN5.png

Comment: It sounds like your system has some issues with your `PATH` environment variable not having some core paths available to it. Perhaps this post will help you see core system paths you are missing (don't remove entries, just look for missing paths from the defaults): https://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-window